# Inject HTML meta tag inside wordpress <head> tag using add_shortcode

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, actions, wp-head

I am trying to add some meta-tag when shortcode `[refresh url='http://stackoverflow.com']` tag is used.

I have done below code, but it is not working, I want to inject HTML code between "`<head>`" tag only when the shortcode is used.

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Plugin
* Description: Plugin
* Version: 1.0
* Author: yolo yolo
* Author URI: https://example.com
*/

$url = '';

function metaRefresh( $atts = array() ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     'url' => 'https://example.com',
    ), $atts));

    return true;
}

add_shortcode('refresh', 'metaRefresh');
add_action('wp_head', 'injectHead', $url);

function injectHead($url){
    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $url; ?>">
    <?php
}


?>
```

Comment: Shortcodes are only parsed in `post_content`, so this approach isn't possible.

Comment: Yes, but can I trigger "wp_head" content inside shortcode function? so that when Wordpress is parsing shortcode, it sees "wp_head" action and takes the other action as well? if you can help me - what would be the best approach, that would be very helpful.

Comment: No, because shortcodes run after `wp_head()` has already finished running. It looks like you're trying to allow editors to enter a redirect; you could set up custom postmeta with a URL input, and in the theme's `header.php` file inside the `<head>` you can have a conditional - if that postmeta isn't empty, output the meta tag with the URL from the postmeta.

Comment: I am doing it vai "plugin", so I don't have access to "header.php"

Comment: Any method that can be done via "plugin" and still be injected in the head tag?

Comment: You should still be able to add postmeta and use that `wp_head()` call to insert the meta tag.

Comment: how to add postmeta? is there any function for that?

Answer (score -1):

First thing, `wp_head` action hook does not accept any argument at all, so am not sure whether the `$url` variable will be passed.

To run the short code properly, you have to  call do_shortcode():

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'refresh_page' );

function refresh_page()
{
    echo do_shortcode( "[refresh url='http://stackoverflow.com']" );
}


add_shortcode( 'refresh',  'refresh_shortcode' );

function refresh_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => '',
    ), $atts, 'refresh' );

    $url = esc_url_raw( $atts['url'] );

    return '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="' . $url . '">';
}
```

Comment: How can I add arguments inside `refresh_page` function so that shortcode can pass `[refresh url='$url']` - I need to pass `argument` inside `refresh_page` function.

Comment: possible to pass an argument inside `refresh_page` function?

Comment: You cannot pass argument to the function. Reason is because the `wp_head` action hook doesn't accept any argument at all. The functionality you are talking about contradict it's implementation. You've got the short code already, then use it. If you need to pass more arguments, then create that support within the short code, not the callback function that is passed to the `wp_head` action hook.

Comment: The context the function is used doesn't allow for passing arguments, but you can pass the arguments in the shorcode, it's the same effect!